# Meteor, выборка данных из MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Всем привет. Сейчас по книжке Discover Meteor знакомлюсь с фреймворком, появился вопрос по коллекциям и вытаскиванию данных из Mongo DB.

Дело в том, что данные не вытаскиваются из базы, они там есть, но не могу достать. Из кода `count()` возвращает 0, а `fetch()` - пустой массив; просто проверяю, делаю выборку, в консоли браузера и там все есть!

Ниже код, который работает не так как надо :)

Создаем коллекцию (/lib/top_list.js) `Top = new Mongo.Collection('top');`
Если отсутствуют данные в таблице, то набиваем их из файла с рыбой (/server/top_list.js)

```
if (Top.find().count() === 0) {
Top.insert({
    author: "autor",
    title: "title"
});

Top.insert({
    author: "author",
    title: "title"
});
```

}

Потом делаем обработку и вывод в шаблон (/views/top/top_list.js):

```
var i = 0, leftPart = [], rightPart = [],
topItems = Top.find(), iMax = topItems.count();
for (i; i < iMax; i +=1) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
        leftPart.push(topItems[i]);
    } else {
        rightPart.push(topItems[i]);
    }
}
Template.topList.helpers({
    "leftTop": leftPart,
    "rightTop": rightPart
});
console.log(iMax);
```

Проверяю и вот что вижу: http://joxi.ru/5mdk09jIdk7Dr1

Answer (score 1):

Так, разобрался, проблема была в файле /views/top/top_list.js
Дело в том, что у меня проверка, получение данных и цикл были до обьявления метеоровского хелпера, а значит и до добавления в него выборки из базы.
немного переработав этот кусок все заработало как надо

```
Template.topList.helpers({
"topList": function () {
    var i = 0, leftPart = [], rightPart = [],
        topItems = Top.find().fetch(), iMax = topItems.length;
    for (i; i < iMax; i +=1) {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            leftPart.push(topItems[i]);
        } else {
            rightPart.push(topItems[i]);
        }
    }
    return {"left":leftPart, "right": rightPart};
}
});
```

Как-то так. Всем спасибо :)